# Applications of chemical reaction networks

Tags: optimization, applications, chemistry

I have recently read a bit on chemical reaction network theory. I was wondering whether the mathematical concepts have cross-field applications like neural networks. For example, can I apply chemical reaction network theory to say optimization of road traffic?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Network theory derives from graph theory, which is the basis for road traffic systems (along with some markov theory and probability, but I suppose that is also used in network theory).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about really cross field applications so far, but the Deficiency Zero Theorem has been applied recently by Rendall to a model of the NFAT signalling pathway by Salazar and Höfer in T-cells and by Sontag for McKeithan’s kinetic proofreading model of T cell activation. So you have some applications in biochemistry or immunology.

Also Horn and Jackson quite early have given examples for certain categories of networks with deficiency zero in "Horn, F. (1973a). Necessary and sufficient conditions for complex balancing in chemical kinetics. Arch. Rat/. Mech. Anal., 49, 172-86." and "Horn, F. & Jackson, R. (1972). General mass action kinetics. Arch. Rat/. Mech. Anal., 47,81-116.".

Answer (score 1):

- Matthew Cook, David Soloveichik, Erik Winfree, Jehoshua Bruck, [Programmability of Chemical Reaction Networks](http://www.paradise.caltech.edu/papers/etr090.pdf), September 2008.
- David Soloveichik, Matthew Cook, Erik Winfree, Jehoshua Bruck, [Computation with Finite Stochastic Chemical Reaction Networks](http://www.paradise.caltech.edu/papers/etr085.pdf), January 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the references contained in the following [paper](http://philjournalsci.dost.gov.ph/images/pdf/pjs_pdf/vol148no2/chemical_reaction_networks_.pdf), for some cross-field applications.